# Powershell Script that recursively searches for specific file and containing directory and copy it to another location

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to write a powershell script that will search recursively for a file and copy it to another location on a local drive with the date appended to it.

However that file could be in multiple different directories. (ex. c:\users\default\Bookmark.txt, c:\users\profile1\Bookmark.txt, c:\users\profile2\Bookmark.txt...etc.)

To distinguish between the different directories I was thinking of appending the directory name containing the file to the filename along with the date. (ex. filename-directoryName-date)

Here is what I have so far:

```
get-childitem -path "$env:userprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data" -filter Bookmarks -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | copy-item -Destination $env:userprofile\Bookmarks-$(get-date -UFormat %d-%m-%Y)
```

This works if it only finds 1 copy of the Bookmarks file and it only appends the date.

To figure out the names of the containing folders I used this command.

```
(get-childitem -path "$env:userprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data" -filter Bookmarks -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force).Directory.Name
```

I need to somehow put this two together and so it outputs :

> c:(whateverlocation)\Bookmark-DirectoryName-Date

I hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan,

When you use the Get-ChildItem command (alias gci) it will return to you an array of DirectoryInfo and FileInfo objects, one for each item it finds.  If you are looking for files called "Bookmarks" (or bookmark.txt...can't tell from your examples which one you're looking for) then you can use the following command to get you a list of all of them:

```
[array]$FileList = gci -Recurse -File -Filter "Bookmarks"
```

The `[array]` designation is necessary to be sure the object is an array regardless of how many items are returned. The filter can have wildcards if you don't know the exact filename.  What that leaves me with is an array object named `$FileList` containing all of the information about the files.  You can read all about the properties and methods available in these objects [at this Microsoft help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8).

For this task, we'll need the `.FullName` property, which tells you the full path & name of each item (which can be used as your source) and the `.BaseName` & `.Extension` properties, which give you the filename and extension respectively.  Using these properties, you can copy each of the files you find to a destination.  Putting it all together, you get something like this:

```
$SourceFolder = "$($env:userprofile)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data"
$DestFolder = '' #Path to Destination Folder
[array]$FileList = gci -Path $SourceFolder -Recurse -File -Filter "Bookmarks"
ForEach ($F in $FileList) {
    Copy-Item $F.FullName (Join-Path $DestFolder ($F.Name + 'stuff to add to end of filename' + $F.Extension))
}
```

In this case, since the files are named 'Bookmarks', the $F.Extension should be blank.  If using a more traditional filename, the pattern above will help you fit your changes in between the filename and the extension.

Hope this helps you out.  If it does, please accept the answer using the check mark on the left.